# Is there a if-else list comprehension in Julia

Tags: list, conditional-statements, julia, list-comprehension

I am trying to use zip in a pythonic way but in Julia. Given two lists:

```
a =[2;3;4;5;6]
b =[0;7;8;9;10]
```

I would like to create the following list comprehension,

```
c = [x for (x,y) in zip(a, b) if (x<y) else y]
```

that returns `c = [0;3;4;5;6]`. Instead I get `syntax: expected "]"` returned.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does that work in Python?

Comment: @StefanKarpinski: Nope. Writing this in Python would fail for the exact same reason as in Julia, with essentially the same fix (although Python's ternary operator syntax is different).

Comment: Python's ternary operator is `x if cond else y` instead of `cond ? x : y`, so the correct Python would be `[x if x<y else y for (x, y) in zip(a, b)]`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to rewrite your comprehension such that the condition is in the generator's "body":

```
c = [x < y ? x : y for (x, y) in zip(a, b)]
```

The `if`-condition in comprehensions is purely for filtering at the moment (although it might be possible to add the meaning you want).

Comment: Instead of the ternary operator, you can also use `ifelse`, which can sometimes be faster (and, you can broadcast it!).